# How do I protect git-assume-unchanged files from being overwritten by remote?

Tags: git, git-push, git-remote

The following behaviour is wondering and annoying me:

1. I have a file in my local repository.
2. I push into the remote repository. (Note: I need the file in my repository!)
3. Now I want to perform local edits, that shall not be pushed remotely (e.g. a configuration customizing for my local machine only).
4. By using `git update-index --assume-unchanged` I tell git not to track changes to this file.
5. But when I do a `git checkout -f`, my local file is overwritten again.

What would be a better way to keep my local changes but not push them remotely? Or: if there is something wrong in my procedure, what should I change?

Comment: Is there a reason you are using `-f` on your checkout?  It seems to contradict what you are trying to accomplish here.

Answer (score 0):

use [.gitignore](https://help.github.com/articles/ignoring-files) to intentionally specify files to ignore.

1 - add file in local (with no specific configuration)
2 - push to remote
3 - add file to .gitignore
4 - customize your local config
5 - do stuff
6 - push to remote
  -> file will be ignored and stay as is on remote.

Comment: But wouldn't this remove the file from the remote repository?

Comment: as long as you don't tell git to remove it (with `git rm --cached filename`) it will stay as is

Comment: Well, but I need the file in my remote repository. So this answer does not help... Sorry

Comment: I've rewrote, maybe more understandable like this

Comment: But now your answer contradicts with your previous answer, "*Note that git will not ignore a file that was already tracked before a rule was added to this file to ignore it.*".